# Toggle Button non functioning on mobile bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I collapse the website the menu items disappear and the toggle button shows in the right side corner, but when I click on it nothing happens its unresponsive.

But when I click on the toggle nothing happens its unresponsive. So making the webpage unusable in mobile view.

I have tried some work arounds with no results, even trying to use a new navbar from bootstrap with the same issue. I have used jquery and javascript CDN and bootstraps CSS and bootstrap javascript still with the same issues.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->


    <title>My Wesite</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>



    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- styles needed for carousel slider -->
    <link href="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">




    <!-- include pace script for automatic web page progress bar  -->
    <script>
        paceOptions = {
            elements: true
        };
    </script>
    <script src="assets/js/pace.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

        <div class="header">
            <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-site navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-md"
                 role="navigation">
                <div class="container">

                <div class="navbar-identity">


                    <a href="posts" class="navbar-brand logo logo-title">
                    <span class="logo-icon"><img class="navbar-brand" src=" assets\image.png" width="180px" height="178px">
                    </span>My<span>Website</span> </a>


              <button data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler pull-right" type="button">

                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 30 30" width="30" height="30" focusable="false"><title>Menu</title><path stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22"/></svg>



                    </button>

</div>






                    <ul class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<li class = "active"><a href="#"> Posts</a></li>



                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="login.php">Login In</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown-item" ><a href="register.php"?>users/register">Register </a>
                    </li>








                                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>logout"><i class=" icon-logout"></i> Log out </a>
                                    </li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="postadd nav-item"><a class="btn btn-block   btn-border btn-post btn-danger nav-link" href="create.php">Post</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- /.header -->
    <div class="search-row-wrapper" style="background-image: url(images/bg.jpg)">
        <div class="inner">
        <div class="container ">
            <form action="#" method="GET">
                <div class="row">



                    <div class="col-md-3">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase the 1st paragraph? It is hard to understand. Also, if you can add some snapshots it would help.

Comment: Done https://imgur.com/a/mnoHe5m the button doesnt work

Comment: Don't put content in comments. [Edit] the question and put all relevant information there.

Comment: I did, thats why I posted the screen shots in a comment, as I do not think screen shots of a toggle button are that relevant or helpful to my question. Along with, this was a reply to a comment. But thank you for your totally useful comment, I am sure you feel better now that you told me to use the edit button, but providing no useful suggestion or inquiry to my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you already use external library to to this, maybe this small script would be a solution to you: https://github.com/grzegorzgit/Litomobile 
You just create menu with ul,li structure and this script automatically creates mobile version. Its simple, but also have some options to customize.